# Write file in the device

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using ReactNative FS library to write a file csv.

I have a problem during the write of the file, for example if I use this:

```
createFile(){
        //Scrivere file
        RNFS.writeFile
            (
            path, 
            this.state.array_acc_sx, 
            'ascii'
            )
        .then((success) => {
            console.log('FILE WRITTEN!');
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
          });
    }
```

I write a document csv with a row whit all the values (This is right)

If I write:

```
RNFS.writeFile
            (
            path, 
            {'LA' : this.state.array_acc_sx, 
            'RA' : this.state.array_acc_dx },
            'ascii'
            )
```

The result is [Object Object]. I have tried to use also JSON.stringfy before the this.state... but it is the same. How can I do??

EDIT1: I have tried to do JSON.stringfy before the {LA : ....} and in this case it writes all in a row. Do you know how can I separate a data for a row?

Thank you

EDIT2: 
What I would to obtain
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a `CSV` file, it is a set of comma separated strings.

```js
const mainString = 'LA,';
const mainString2 = 'RA,';
const rowString = this.state.array_acc_sx.map(arr => `${arr[0]},${arr[1]}\n`).join('');
const rowString2 = this.state.array_acc_dx.map(arr => `${arr[0]},${arr[1]}\n`).join('');
const rowValue = mainString + rowString
const rowValue2 = mainString2 + rowString2
const csvValue = `${rowValue} \n ${rowValue2}`;

RNFS.writeFile(path, csvValue, 'utf8')
  .then((success) => {
    console.log('FILE WRITTEN!',success);
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You are using RNFetchBlob? It is the same with react-native-fs
?

Comment: The method of use is the same. My answers have been corrected.

Comment: I'm trying and thank you :) Could you please explain what did you do with `${arr[0]},${arr[1]}\n`).join(''); ?

Comment: I have tried your code and it works but the data are wrote for columns and not rows

Comment: @Jack23 Take the value of the arrangement you have, add a comma, and arrange it in two vertical rows.

Comment: What is the current value and what shape do you want?

Comment: I would have: 
row1: LA | this.state.array_acc_sx 
row2: RA | this.state.array_acc_dx

Comment: at the moment I have Column1: LA Row2: value. Column2: RA, Row2: value.

@I Edit the first post :)

Comment: @Jack23  I modified my answer to your comments.

Comment: sorry for the question, it prints only one row with all values ||| I'm trying after your edit

Comment: @Jack23 OK, I added '\n' writing to the code of the answer. Would you like to try again?

Answer (score 0):

Should be correctly stringified like this:

```
RNFS.writeFile(path,JSON.stringify({'LA' : this.state.array_acc_sx, 'RA' : this.state.array_acc_dx }),'ascii')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) but all the data are write in a single row, I need that every data are written in a different row, do you know how can I do??